# CSS selector getting parent when you know the child

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div id"mainDiv">
        <ul id="cat1">
        </ul>
</div>

<div id"mainDiv">
        <ul id="cat2">
        </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to select the "mainDiv" which has a child ul "cat1", in my CSS as I want to apply some styling on that div. But not the all maindiv's

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't have more than 1 element with the same id. So that's already invalid HTML.

Comment: There is no way to select an ancestor with CSS currently.  Selectors level 4 introduces the "context" of a selector which would allow this, but this is not supported by any major browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No CSS selector for this currently, so you're going to have to resort to some JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('#cat2').parent().css(/* add it here */);
```

Comment: you can use the nth-child(n) psuedo selector or even first-child

Comment: Eh? How would you go about styling the parent given only the child id and `nth-child`? I thought that went down, not up.

Comment: According to WC3 spec: E:nth-child(n) an E element, the n-th child of its parent

Comment: @Charles380: That gets you the child, not the parent.

Comment: @BoltClock According to WC3 CSS3 standards the nth-child(n) psuedo class does the following. The :nth-child(an+b) pseudo-class notation represents an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for any positive integer or zero value of n, and has a parent element.

Comment: and I am realizing I must have clicked the wrong keyword because this question isn't related to HTML5/CSS3 specifically.

Comment: @Charles380: Exactly. So you're getting the child, not the parent.

Comment: @BoltClock I stand corrected I thought I was browsing the HTML5/CSS3 questions but I must have hit my html favorite keyword instead of html5

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is invalid:

```
<div id"mainDiv">
```

should be

```
<div id="mainDiv">
```

Since duplicate ID's are invalid in HTML, your question is really invalid in this context.
You should either use a class OR rethink your structure.

Example for the first div:

```
<div class="mainDiv firstdiv">
```

and subsequent divs:

```
<div class="mainDiv">
```

CSS:

```
.firstdif{}
```

put your CSS in that.